# Padding between multibutton components

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to add padding between the multibutton components. I did getStyle().setPaddingTop(10) but this pads within the component, not the outside of the border. I also have a border for the component. So, it shows clearly where the padding happens.

I used getStyle().setPaddingTop(10). Isn't it supposed to be padding and then border instead of the border and then padding getting applied?

```
/**
 * Padding between two items in my own class MultiButtonCC extended from MultiButton class
 */
    public void setPadding(int px) {
        getStyle().setPaddingTop(px);
    }
```

This is in my main form class

```
InfiniteContainer ic = new InfiniteContainer() {
            @Override
            public Component[] fetchComponents(int index, int amount) {
                java.util.List<Map<String, Object>> data = fetchGateData();
                MultiButtonCC[] cmps = new MultiButtonCC[data.size()];
                for (int iter = 0; iter < cmps.length; iter++) {
                    Map<String, Object> currentList = data.get(iter);
                    if (currentList == null) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    cmps[iter] = new MultiButtonCC();
                    cmps[iter].setTextLine1("Gate                   Airline                Code");
                    cmps[iter].setPadding(30);
                    //cmps[iter].getAllStyles().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_MONOSPACE, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
                    cmps[iter].getStyle().setBorder(border);
                    cmps[iter].setTextLine2("T2 51A, 57   American      A B C D E F");
                }
                return cmps;
            }
        };
```

```
.................. Padding
 x px
 ----------------- Border
| Line 1          |
| Line 2          |
 ------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself. It is the margin that provides the functionality that I am looking for. Got switched the functionality padding and margin by mistake.
I solved by adding:

```
/**
 * Set margin around the item
 */
public void setMargin(int px) {
    getStyle().setMarginTop(px);
}
```

Comment: That's correct. FYI you should use `getUnselectedStyle()` or in this case `getAllStyles()` as `getStyle()` will return the current style which might change based on component state.